# Как реализовать свои emoji?

Tags: веб-программирование

Заинтересовал такой вопрос, как можно реализовать свои emoji? Представим, у меня имеется пак с картинками этих emoji, в форме у меня имеется выбор этих emoji, допустим я вставил этот смайлик, но вдруг я его захотел скопировать потом вставить, вот как такое работает? У меня свои emoji

Comment: Технически, Emoji — это не картинки, а символы в юникоде, копируются и вставляются они точно так же как и любой другой текст. Если вы хотите новый Emoji, то «честный» способ — написать в Концорсиум Юникода предложение добавить новый символ и надеяться, что они примут его; «не совсем честный» — впихнуть свой символ в Private Use Area и создать шрифт с нужными вам картинками для впихнутых вами символов; «совсем нечестный» — тупо ставить `<img>` вместо символов, но естественно это уже не будет иметь никакого отношения к Emoji и нормально копироваться оно не будет